# Why Stack in java cannot be created with type parameter(generic)

Tags: java, generic-collections

`Stack` is a generic class in Java, it definition is class `Stack<E> extends Vector<E>`, but why I cannot instantiate it with type parameter like `Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>();` But a `Vector` can?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right `Stack` class?

Comment: You are in Java 7, right? In Java 6 you'd have to `...= new Stack<Integer>()`. Do you have a compiler output for us?

Comment: Please try to reproduce this with a short but complete program. I suspect that in trying to do so, you'll work out what you've been doing wrong (like trying it with your own non-generic Stack class).

Comment: Btw, `Stack` (and `Vector`) are more or less obsolete. For non-threadsafe use (e.g. on a single thread), you should use an implementation of [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) such as `ArrayDeque`. For multithreaded use, an implementation of `BlockingDeque` is probably best.

Comment: Try using import java.util.Stack;

Comment: Im not quite sure but if `Stack<E> extends Vector<E>` then `E` is not the same in both classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it can.

```java
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
```

Comment: Oh! I created a Stack.java file in the same directory and I think that's the reason. But I also import the java.util.Stack, why it will refer to the Stack I created? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what went wrong with your code. Even if I have a Stack class in the same package and use import java.util.Stack in my other class, it is the correct (util) Stack.